# SharePoint 2013 BCS Action mailto not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, bcs

I have SharePoint 2013 and I am using BCS to show data from external database. For this external content type I have an action "mailto:{0}", it does not work and generates error "Could not redirect to the action URL because it was not well formed.  Contact your system administrator.". An action for same external data source which is "http://mysiteABC:80/Person.aspx?accountname={0} " is working perfectly fine.

So my question is how do we make mailto links work with BCS actions?

Comment: So no response from anyone, I am still waiting. Any ideas/work arounds are welcome because I have no clue how to make it work